# PHP + MySQL - will not read from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a website project for school which requires a log in page. I already have the PHP set up to write to the database, that works no problem. My new problem is that nothing will actually read from the database. I am testing on my localhost, connection is fine. My error I receive is that the email is incorrect, when in fact it is valid. Hopefully you guys can pick up on an easy problem for me! Thanks!

PHP:

```
<?php

//Setup our DB connection
include('../../connect/local-connect.php');

// Get the user entered elements
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pword = $_POST['password'];

// email query
$query = "SELECT email FROM project WHERE email = '$email'";

//Run email query
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Read error - email');

// # of results
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    header('Location:login.php?logerror=1');
    exit;
}

//If we got here, we have validated the email

// Build the username query
$query = "SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$pword'";

// Run the password query
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Read error - password');

// Did we get a row?
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    header('Location:login.php?logerror=2');
    exit;
}

// If we got here, we have validated an email and password combo.

//  Close the DB connection
mysqli_close ($dbc);

// Start a PHP session
session_start();

//Get and store our session variables
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['sname']=$row['name'];
header('Location:custwelcome.php');
exit;

// Pass a '3' back to login.php for testing (Keep this code at the bottom!)
header('Location:login.php?logerror=3');
exit;

    ?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- 
XXXX 
login.php 
-->

<?php
    //  Start a PHP session
    session_start();

    // Check to see if user is already logged in
    if(isset($_SESSION["sname"]))
    {
        header('Location:custwelcome.php');
        exit;
    }

?>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Meta tag -->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex.nofollow" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Link tag for CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet/project.css" />

    <!-- Javascript tags -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/messages.js"></script>


    <!-- Web Page Title -->
    <title>Login Page</title>

  </head>

<body>
    <div id="header">

                <img src="../images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />

        <p class="sh1">Shoe Source Unlimited</p>
        <p class="sh2">Your source for lightning sales of this season's hot shoes!    </p>

        <p class="sh3">LeAndra Marx</p>
  </div>

    <div id="navbar">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="../homepage.htm">Home</a>                          
             </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Men's</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="../sneakers.htm">Sneakers</a></li>
                         <li><a href="../loafers.htm">Loafers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../athletic.htm">Athletic</a></li>
                    </ul>                       
            </li>

             <li>
                <a href="#">Women's</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="../boots.htm">Boots</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../heels.htm">Heels</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../sandals.htm">Sandals</a></li>       
                    </ul>               
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="../about.htm">About Us</a>         

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="../signup.htm">Sign Up</a>

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="login.php">Log In</a>

            </li>

        </ul>   
    </div>





  <div id="external">

    <p>

            <a href="https://twitter.com/XXXXX"     onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">
                <img src="../images/twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" />
            </a>
    </p>
            <p>Follow us on Twitter!</p>
        <br/>


    <p>

            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ShoeSourceUnlimited" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">
                <img src="../images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" />
            </a>
    </p>
            <p>Like us on Facebook!</p>
        <br/>


         <a href="email/projectem.htm">
        <img src="../images/email.jpg" alt="pinkemail"  />
        </a>

            <p> Send us an email!</p>   
     </div> 


    <div id="main">
        <p>Sign in below to start making purchases!</p>

    </div>


    <p id="registered"> Don't have an account? Sign up <a     href="../signup.htm">here</a>!
    <div id="userform">
        <p class="fh">Log In Here</p>

        <form id="loginform" action="logincheck.php" method="post">

                <?php
                // Check return codes from logincheck.php
                if ($_GET["logerror"] == 1)
                {
                    echo '<p class="loginerror">Invalid Email!</p>';
                }
                if ($_GET["logerror"] == 2)
                {
                    echo '<p class="loginerror">Invalid Password!</p>';
                }
                if ($_GET["logerror"] == 3)
                {
                    echo '<p class="loginerror">Returned from     logincheck</p>';
                }
            ?>

            <p>

                <!--Email -->
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required autofocus
                title="Email: 6-59 characters, lowercase, valid email only!"
                pattern="[a-z0-9.-_]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}"
                maxlength="60"
                onfocus="emailmsg()" />
                <br />

                <!--Password -->
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required
                title="Password: 5-15 characters, U/L, 0-9, . - _ ! $ only!"
                pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_!$]{5,15}" 
                onchange="form.reenter.pattern=this.value;"
                onfocus="passmsg()"/>
                <br />


 <!-- Build buttons so that they are consistent throughout the site 
                never use get method for confidential data-->
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" 
                value=" Log In! "
                onfocus="signmsg()"/> 


                <span class="reset">

                    <input type="reset" value=" Clear "     onclick="history.go(0)" 
                    onfocus="clearmsg()"/>
                </span>
            </p>

        </form>

    </div>

    <div id="messages">
    <p></p>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>

            &copy;2014, XXXX

        </p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Let me know if any more files need to be looked at I just figured the issue lay in these two files.

MY SOLUTION: All I did was change my table name and it somehow started to work. So that's good, I guess! Thanks to everyone who tried to help :)

Comment: Try wrapping the `email` WHERE clause in backticks.

Comment: Why? It's not a reserved word.

Comment: OT: It's a bad idea to give a different error for incorrect username and incorrect password.

Comment: If you `echo $query`, and then try to run that query by hand, does it return the expected row?

Comment: As part of my assignment, separate incorrect errors have to be present.

Comment: When I change the code in my php to say:  $query = "SELECT email FROM project WHERE email = 'test@test.com'"; (a valid email in the database that also works just fine when i run a sql search by hand there), i still receive the error message through the page

Comment: You're closing your DB connection (prematurely) then trying to access `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`. That's the major issue here. Either get rid of the `mysqli_close ($dbc);` or place it near the bottom. You don't really need it anyway.

Comment: I tried getting rid of the mysqli_close mysqli_fetch_array($result); -- did not help. I tried moving it to the bottom. Also did not help.

Comment: Then instead of `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)` try `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ echo "Success";}` checking for success first, instead of if the query fails. This being for `$query = "SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$pword'";` which theoretically, should work.

Comment: Plus, I didn't say to get rid of `mysqli_fetch_array($result);` I said to get rid of `mysqli_close ($dbc);`

Comment: Ok, never mind all of what I've said above. Your code checks out, I've tested it. Either your HTML form's JS is failing you, or you don't have data in your DB to match against used login credentials. Try using a form with no JS at all, just a plain 'ol regular standard form with sufficient fields to access DB.

Comment: I tried removing all javascript from my html form - it did not improve the situation.

Comment: I have seen past cases where using `type="email"` did not work and the OP had to use `type="text"` so try that. As I said earlier, I tested your code and it worked.

Comment: `error I receive is that the email is incorrect`. Sorry but i could not guess whether it was server side(php) error or client side(javascript) error. Can you paste the exact error string ? `onfocus="emailmsg()"` is the one calling javascript function, i suppose, so change or remove that to test. Similarly, `$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Read error - email');` this line is php error. Change or remove to test.

Answer (score 0):

is your database connection ok? at first check is connection establish perfectly.

an on top of database connection file please on error reporting to find out error

```
error_reporing(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

and after database connection use following syntax.. you will get all if any failure in connection

```
mysql_connect('host','username','password') OR die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('dbName') OR die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: He's using `mysqli`, not `mysql`.

Comment: but error reporting will work here .. and after connection can check is it established or not

Comment: But you have to use `mysqli_connect`, not `mysql_connect`, and `mysqli_connect_error()`, not `mysql_error()`.

Comment: You know the difference between `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`, don't you? If not, you may want to educate yourself before answering too many more PHP+MySQL questions.

Comment: My connection is fine. I tested that by changing the password in my connection file and then the error changed to "cannot connect to database". 

I'm honestly not too savvy with php. I'm doing it for a college class and it was crammed in during the last week, so a lot of what you're asking is pretty confusing. Can you simplify your comment for me?

Comment: i had mention in my next answer please check...

as i know mysql is old driver and MySQLi is the Improved driver. MySQLi takes advantage of the newer features of MySQL 5

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","my_db");


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

for mysqli

Comment: Can you explain this a little better? I'm not too familiar with php/mysql and only got a crash course before being thrown to the sharks.

Comment: basically its a connection to database. and once you establish it you just need to include/required_once that file top of the php page on which you need to query.

Comment: its cause you close the connection after query. and need to reestablish again for next. if there is no such as required to close the connection, just comment this line of code and try. i hope it will work fine. and you need to close connection you have to include connection file again..

Comment: @Sach - explain it in the answer above, not the comments ;) Then, delete the comments. You can edit the answer by clicking **edit**.